# I want Do - While Loop including If Else Statement

Tags: java, selenium, for-loop, conditional-statements, do-while

Hi need a response from this...

I have code for
1. Opening Firefox
2. Insert Username & Password

Check these reference images

[Goto https://mettl.com/corporate/live-feed#/proctoringDashboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tW2rE.jpg)

[Click -> Select All](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4LHl0.jpg)

[Click -> Authorize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWPt5.jpg)

[Find "No more candidates awaiting Authorization"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2CJp.jpg)

[Click -> All Tests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tgGBI.jpg)

Once find a Candidate Name or Email Address, instead of "No more candidates awaiting Authorization" Wait 10 Seconds then wait for Mouse Click

Like below

[Find Candidate Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0J1T4.jpg)

for e-g

We have 100 Candidates in online, when the candidate details are corrected, i copy the Name, E-mail ID & Date of Birth, if its not corrected then back to All Tests

Kindly check my following code

```
package com.selenium.wipro.sample;    

import java.io.File;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxBinary;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxOptions;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class ExampleScanrio {

public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException

    {
     System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\Users\\Yaser\\dist\\geckodriver-master\\geckodriver.exe");
     File pathBinary = new File("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");
     FirefoxBinary firefoxbinary = new FirefoxBinary(pathBinary);
     DesiredCapabilities desired = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
     FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
     desired.setCapability(FirefoxOptions.FIREFOX_OPTIONS, options.setBinary(firefoxbinary));       
     WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
     driver.get("https://mettl.com/corporate/login");
     driver.manage().window().maximize();
     driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys("sometext");
     driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys("sometext");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@type='submit']")).click();

     driver.navigate().to("https://mettl.com/corporate/live-feed#/proctoringDashboard");

     WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,50);
     wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[@class='pull-left']")));

     // Click -> AllTests
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='pull-left']")).click();

     // Click -> Authorize
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Authorize')]")).click();

     // Find String     
     String tt = "No more candidates awaiting Authorization";
     String nomore = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='ng-scope' and contains(@data-ng-if,'newRequestReceived')]//p[@class='ng-scope' and contains(@data-ng-if,'authRequestCount')]"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");

     // i need condition Statement and Loop Statement here
     // It might be wrong please give a correct Statement

    boolean run = true;

    while(run)
    {
        if (nomore.contentEquals(tt))
            {
            driver.navigate().to("https://mettl.com/corporate/live-feed#/proctoringDashboard");
            //Thread.sleep(750);
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@class='checkbox ng-binding']//input[@type='checkbox']")).click();
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Authorize')]")).click();
            Thread.sleep(1200);
            System.out.println("Not Available");

            }

        else
            {
            System.out.println("Available");
            //Thread.sleep(10000);
            run = false;
            //break;                                    
            } 

        } 


    }
}
```

and error like this

```
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: true, browserName: firefox, browserVersion: 63.0.1, javascriptEnabled: true, moz:accessibilityChecks: false, moz:geckodriverVersion: 0.23.0, moz:headless: false, moz:processID: 20324, moz:profile: C:\Users\Yaser\AppData\Loca..., moz:useNonSpecCompliantPointerOrigin: false, moz:webdriverClick: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, platformVersion: 10.0, rotatable: false, setWindowRect: true, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: 39efeef7-4514-4b83-b31b-deaf937ee098
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, value=//label[@class='checkbox ng-binding']//input[@type='checkbox']}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByXPath(RemoteWebDriver.java:428)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByXPath.findElement(By.java:353)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at automation.ExampleScanario.main(ExampleScanario.java:52)
```

Please help me to work on this, i am not Software Engineer, Kindly consider my poor English knowledge and beginner of Java

Finally

when candidates data shown the window

copy these date to Notepad

Xpath Location

```
//span[@title='First Name']
//span[@title='Date of Birth']
//span[@title='Email Address']
```

thank you

Yaser B

Comment: I haven't looked to closely at the rest of your code, and I'm not sure what you're trying to accomplish with the `do-while` and `if-else` statements, but your current `do-while` implementation is wrong. Instead of `do(True){ ... }while()` it should be `do{ ... }while(true);`. Note how the `true` (with lowercase `t`) is inside the `while(true)` part instead of the `do`, and in addition, there is a semi-colon (`;`) behind the `while(true);`. Make sure to also add a `break` somewhere in your do-while loop however, otherwise it will just keep on looping indefinitely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should work like this:

```
String tt = "No more candidates awaiting Authorization";
String nomore = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[@class='ng-scope' and contains(@data-ng-if,'newRequestReceived')]//p[@class='ng-scope' and contains(@data-ng-if,'authRequestCount')]"))).getAttribute("innerHTML");


boolean run = true;

while(run)
{
    if (nomore.contentEquals(tt))
        {
        driver.navigate().to("https://mettl.com/corporate/live-feed#/proctoringDashboard");
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@class='checkbox ng-binding']//input[@type='checkbox']")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[contains(text(),'Authorize')]")).click();
        Thread.sleep(750);
        System.out.println("Not Available");

        }
    else
        {
        System.out.println("Available");
        //Thread.sleep(10000);
        //break;
        run = false; /*Stopps the loop*/                           
        } 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what you exactly want to do but try this loop:

```
boolean run = true;

while(run){
  if(statement){
    Do something
  }else{
    Do something else
  }
}
```

This is an infinity loop; To avoid this you can set run to false it will stop.

Sincerely Silvan

Comment: can you please explain give one example, infinity loop program

Comment: Sorry, what exactly should I explain? How an infinity loop works?